# What is the use of vinegar as a component in ancient ink receipes?

Tags: roman-empire, archaeology, literature

Quite some receipes of old (pre-iron-gall) ink seem to include vinegar. It is of pale colour though, and it may or may not be corrosive to the paper. Whats it's use?

Comment: I don't know about pre-iron-gall recipes, but vinegar was a common component of invisible inks during Renaissance.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, can you supply or reference some examples of such recipes? I believe it's because vinegar provided a better solvent (than water) for improving the ink's consistency. Wine is another common solvent for the same reason.

Answer (score 4):

A quick google with words 'vinegar ink recipe' brings up [this](http://www.thehippyhomemaker.com/homemade-ink-feather-pen/):

INGREDIENTS

1/2 cup black walnut hull powder (or other ink herb of
   choice)

4 cups filtered water.

1 cup extra strong brewed herbal
   infusion.

**1 tsp. distilled white vinegar (a natural mordant to help the color last longer and stay)**

1 tsp. ... binder to thicken and keep the ink
on the paper (optional – see below)

---

The wiki entry for [mordant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordant):

> A mordant or dye fixative is a substance used to set (i.e. bind) dyes
>   on fabrics by forming a coordination complex with the dye, which then
>   attaches to the fabric (or tissue). It may be used for dyeing fabrics
>   or for intensifying stains in cell or tissue preparations.

---

An old article has this to say concerning the use of mordants with inks(emphasis mine):

> The ink first used probably was some natural animal pigment such as
>   the black fluid obtained from various species of cuttle fish but the
>   limited supply of this material soon led to the use of a mechanical
>   mixture of water gum and lamp black and the characters were painted
>   rather than written by means of a broad pointed reed As ink of this
>   simple nature was easily removed from the surface of the parchment by
>   the mere application of moisture it was early found necessary to
>   contrive some means of forming a more durable ink and for this purpose
>   the expedient was adopted of treating the mixture with some substance
>   **such as vinegar of the nature of a mordant** which would penetrate the
>   parchment written upon and form an ink not liable to fade A chemical
>   dye consisting of an infusion of galls with sulphate of iron was
>   afterwards used as from its vitreous nature it bit into the medium
>   employed...
>
> [Chamber's Journal of Popular Literature, Science and Arts](https://books.google.com/books?id=_iYZAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA187&dq=use%20of%20vinegar%20as%20mordant%20in%20ink&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7n6Hy7P7YAhUY2WMKHVHwDf4Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=use%20of%20vinegar%20as%20mordant%20in%20ink&f=false) W & R
>   Chambers, 1891 - London (England)

Comment: A mordant is used when dying clothes, because it makes colour last longer and stay - when washed. Writing is not washed, and i do not see what a mordant would do.

Comment: @HannesH, updated with more info relevant to the use of mordants to help set inks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid the ink spoiled with fungi, they added some vinegar...

Comment: Do you have a source for this claim?